# installed homebrew openssl library not found when building MongoDb PHP driver on Mac

Tags: php, php-fpm, openssl

Similar to [this questioner](https://serverfault.com/questions/1140644/nginx-php-fpm-8-1-502-bad-gateway-site-down-for-hours-until-php-fpm-manual), due to a `502 Bad Gateway` error, following the [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.manual.php) I am attempting to build the PHP Mongo driver from scratch, using a modified `./config` step

```
./configure --with-mongodb-ssl=openssl CFLAGS='-I /opt/homebrew/include'
```

I also have the Homebrew `openssl@3` installed at `/opt/homebrew/include/openssl`, which is a symlink to `/Cellar/openssl@3/3.1.3/include/openssl`.

However, when I run the config command, I get these errors that it can't find it:

```
checking whether to enable crypto and TLS... openssl
checking deprecated option for OpenSSL library path... auto
checking for cc options needed to detect all undeclared functions... none needed
configure: checking whether OpenSSL is available
checking for openssl... no
checking for EVP_DigestInit_ex in -lcrypto... no
configure: checking whether OpenSSL >= 1.1.0 is available
checking for OPENSSL_init_ssl in -lssl... no
configure: checking whether OpenSSL < 1.1.0 is available
checking for SSL_library_init in -lssl... no
configure: error: OpenSSL libraries and development headers could not be found
```

FWIW, I also have `openssl@1.1` installed, but when I attempt to uninstall it, I get a message that it is required by `pickle`.

Could that installation be causing a conflict somehow? Or is there something else I need to fix?

Answer (score 0):

So my issue was simply that I did not have `pkg-config` installed. Once I installed it via homebrew (`brew install phg-config`), it built fine.

Comment: You might fix the typo and then accept your own answer.